# remove @reply in embedded Twitter timeline using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm customizing my embedded Twitter timeline. I thought their was an option to remove the @replies with `show-replies='false'` but that doesn't seem to work.

I can remove the 'Replying to @twitter' div with jquery by using:

```
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.timeline-Tweet-inReplyTo').css('display', 'none');
```

but I can't remove the @reply `<p>` text that follows immediately after.

Here's the html ...

```
<div class="timeline-Tweet-inReplyTo"><a class="u-linkBlend" data-scribe="element:in_reply_to_user_link" href="https://twitter.com/_/status/######">
  Replying to @twitter
</a>
</div>
<p class="timeline-Tweet-text" lang="en" dir="ltr" style="margin: 0px;">twit tweet twitter</p>
```

Current jquery ...

```
jQuery('.twitter-block').delegate( '#twitter-widget-0','DOMSubtreeModified propertychange', function(){customizeTweetMedia();} );
var customizeTweetMedia = function()
{ 
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('p.timeline-tweet-text').css('margin', '0');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('img.Avatar').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a different selector to target the `p` as well as the preceding `div`.

Also not that you can simplify your logic; you don't need `contents()` and the `find()` calls can be joined together. Try this:

```
$('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline div.timeline-Tweet-inReplyTo, .twitter-timeline p.timeline-Tweet-text').hide();
```

Comment: That seems to remove all tweets. I just want to remove the tweet immediately following div.tmieline-Tweet-inReplyTo

Answer (score 0):

```
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.timeline-Tweet-inReplyTo').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.timeline-Tweet-inReplyTo').nextAll('p.timeline-Tweet-text').css('display', 'none');
```